# HTML <textarea> only sends '\n' back to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

Our application has both a .NET offline application (WinForms and WPF), as well as online ASP.NET MVC.

Our offline application represents new lines with /r/n (Carriage Return + Line Feed).

When we put these onto an online form, specifically a textarea - if the user changes anything in the textarea, the browser automatically removes all /r characters from the text. Thus breaking the offline counterparts.

Oddly if the user doesn't change anything, carriage returns are preserved.

Ideally I don't want to fix this on a case by case basis, because that would be a lot of wasted effort.

Is there any way I can use an MVC Filter to convert \n => \r\n where \r isn't present. Or if that isn't possible, we're already using a JSON.NET value provider factory to parse JSON [as discussed here](https://json.codeplex.com/discussions/347099) - maybe I could intercept string values at this point?

Has anyone else got any experience with this, what is my best option?

Comment: My first idea would be to `.Replace("\n", "\r\n").Replace("\r\r", "\r")`. But that might not be the most efficient way of going about it.

Comment: how about encoding the carriage returns/etc into ascii?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As time is short I've had to implement something quickly so I've tacked something into the `JsonNetValueProviderFactory` which just does some Regex replacements. Probably isn't the speediest of things but seems to do the trick.

I'll leave this unanswered for a while just in case a better solution arises.

```
private static readonly System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex _orphanEOLChecker =
    new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"((?<!\r)\n)|(\r(?!\n))",
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled &
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);
private const string _newLineReplacement = "\r\n";

private static string FixCarriageReturns(string val)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
        return val;

    return _orphanEOLChecker.Replace(val, _newLineReplacement);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and adding your own solution for future users faced with the same problem!